# Designing a website in Phases - allowing for future content

Tags: navigation, menu

I am in the process of designing a website which will be produced in at least 2 phases. The first release will include the majority of the site sections but in phase 2 we will be producing additional functionality.

This means that some sections of the website will only include a single subsection initially but will expand to several subsections at a later date.

My question is: **Should I still include a sub-menu for the sections that only have 1 sub-section** for now to keep the site consistent and so that the site doesn't appear to restructure itself when we release phase 2, or should the sub-menu be excluded for now and only introduced when there is sufficient content?

I think I'm leaning more toward excluding the menu for now but would value other opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with excluding the menu for now as well.

A big reason for this is that you (or the customer) might decide that a different design is also needed which removes the need to for sub-menus or reorganises them in some other way.

Also having a sub menu might lead users to think that they are missing something that they should have access to *now* (rather than being the promise of new functionality).

However another factor to bear in mind is the time between the release of the phases. A short time doesn't give users time to get entrenched in their ways making a transition to a new menu structure easier for users. This would lead to not having the placeholder sub menus.

If there is a longer time then it *could* be an argument for having the placeholder so there is less disruption when the new features are finally released.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit worried that having a menu that is obviously incomplete would be akin to the old 'Under Construction' messages of 10 years ago, so I agree that we don't want the users thinking they are missing some features.

Answer (score 2):

In short and in principle: I would always rank “making sense” much higher than “being consistent”. Consistence is often overrated, anyway – (semantic) *coherence* and *discoverability* are much more important.

Hence, apart from the fact that you cannot know what other changes might or will be introduced within the 2nd project phase: an interface element (i.e. your submenu) without the content/functionality to justify its existence is the interface equivalent to a Potemkin village – do not build one unless you need to trick the czar. ;-)

Comment: The consistency comment made me think of the 'Enter' button on the iPad. Changing the label to be something appropriate (save, login, Go, etc) is a perfect example of how consistency doesn't mean be exactly the same.